# adding a leftBarButtonItem crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I am trying to set my leftBarButtonItem to my navigation item via the following code:

```
  UIBarButtonItem * leftSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    leftSpacer.width = 10;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftSpacer;
```

However, it gives me a program received SIGABRT. Why is this?

Comment: no mistake here. so we need more context. where are you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

use some of this code that may helps you.

```
// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    // create a standard "add" button
    UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
    bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    // create a spacer
    bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    // create a standard "refresh" button
    bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
    bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:bi];

    // stick the buttons in the toolbar
    [tb setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
    self.navigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tb];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample shows you alloc and init the bar button item, but you show no release. Do you release it? `[leftSpacer release]`

Comment: how is it that not releasing it crashes the app, it will just leak it

Comment: i don't know much about alloc and releas only that if arc is on in wil give warnings and errors and i didn't so i was thinking this code was right.